# Sintaxis para 'Postfix Completion' en el IDE PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, autocompletar, autocomplete, snippets, postfix

Vengo de VSCode y me estoy personalizando los `snippets`/`Postfix Completion`-s de PyCharm pero no sé la sintaxis correcta para expresiones más avanzadas que un simple `$EXPR$.key`.

La [página oficial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-postfix-completion.html) de `JeyBrains` contiene documentación y ejemplos mínimos y en Internet tampoco hay mucha información al respecto.

Lo que quiero hacer es **analizar la expresión y dividirla**, aplicado a un ejemplo, sería lo siguiente:

Before:

```
pygame.locals.*.from
```

After:

```
# librería, función = $EXPR$.rsplit(".", 1)
from pygame.locals import *  # from libreria import función
```

En el ejemplo, se divide la expresión en el último punto. Aparte de eso, me pregunto si se puede **meter un condicional** para poder juntar ese snippet con otro y, en vez de tener el snippet 'from' e 'import', tener solo uno.

Ejemplo de función en python:

```
if $EXPR$.__contains__("."):
    # Lo mismo de arriba
else:
    import $EXPR$  # El otro snippet
```

Llevándo esto un poco más lejos, también me pregunto si en vez de importar solo una función/clase quisiera **importar más de uno**, se podría modificar la sintaxis de tal manera que las funciones estuviesen en **forma de tupla**. Explicación visual:

Before:

```
pygame.sprite.(Sprite, Group).import
```

After:

```
from pygame.sprite import Sprite, Group
```

Bajando el nivel un poco, también se me ocurre la siguiente implementación que no sé como aplicar mediante un `Postfix Completion`.

Before:

```
(pygame, os).import
```

After:

```
import pygame
import os
```

Este ejemplo importa las librerías dentro de la `$EXPR$` de tipo tupla, se podría mejorar añadiendo lo mismo que en la anterior, es decir, para cada elemento en la tupla, dividirlo si contiene puntos y hacer un `from ... import ...`.

Por último, os dejo un ejemplo predefinido de PyCharm en el que dados dos números divididos por una coma y un espacio, el snippet, cuya `key` es "par", crea una tupla.

Before:

```
def f():
    a = 1, 2.par
    return a
```

After:

```
def f():
    a = (1, 2)
    return a
```

Comment: Yo creo que es más útil que Pycharm importe los módulos automáticamente

Comment: @Mateo, es un mero ejemplo explicativo que he elegido para reflejar mis dudas de una manera sencilla y entendible. Aunque el ejemplo no demuestre que sea útil, creo que el principal objetivo lo cumple.